# Scrollable TableLayout android

Tags: android, sqlite, scrollview, tablelayout

I have problem with my app.I have SQLite database it works fine. I have activity where user choose date range and when user clicks button It should open table with data. It worked when I didn't use ScrollView. Now It gives error about too many childs. I am beginner, can you please help me how to fix it?
My code .xml:

```
<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scroll"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#00ffedff"
   android:fadeScrollbars="false"
   android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
   android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"  >

<TableLayout
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:background="#73ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/nos"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
    </TableRow>
  <TableLayout/>
<Scrollview/>
```

java:

```
 String query = "SELECT * from  Dienasgramata WHERE Datums BETWEEN'" + min +    "'  AND  '" + max + "'  ";
    Log.d("MyQuery", query);


  Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();



    for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Date")));
        textView1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        ......

        textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        ......
        tableRow.addView(textView1);
       ......
        tableRow.addView(tableLayout);



        c.moveToNext() ;



    }
   c.close();


    setContentView(tableLayout);

    database.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Database can contain too many records and tablet layout will consume too much memory. Switch to [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)